# Computing absolute position from relative and absolute base

Tags: java, android, gps, coordinate-transformation

I am developing a system that generates relative positions, and have supplied it with an absolute base position. This way, I can compute, for each relative position, the corresponding absolute position.

But I am having trouble finding a solution for this, and cannot work it out because it is not trivial (the relative coordinates are based on a flat coordinate system, and the absolute is Latitude and Longitude, in decimal degrees format).

To elaborate a bit further, I start on a relative position of (0,0) and record what that position translates to in absolute positioning, namely decimal degrees notation, as provided by the Android Location API. I then compute offsets respective to each component, which will result in a new relative position.

Has anyone found a solution in the Java (or a similar) programming language to compute an absolute position (in the same decimal degrees format I mentioned) corresponding to this last relative position? Even just the formulas would do.

Comment: Your question is way too vague? I mean relative and absolute coordinates can be defined to be anything. You could have two objects whose relative coordinates are their X and Y offset from each other, and their absolute coordinates as their X and Y offset from (0, 0) of the screen, but then what would be your question?

Comment: What I meant was this: I compute relative positions from successive offsets, starting at (0,0), and adding in offsets in meters. I also register what is the absolute position on (0,0), where I should add the offset between that point and the relative position (in practical terms, the offset is the coordinate value, since the point itself has X and Y values of 0). I shall update the question.

Comment: Now you need to define the absolute position coordinate system.

Comment: By "decimal degrees" do you mean longitude and latitude on the Earth's surface?

Comment: That's exactly it! I thought it wasn't that relevant, but yes: these are the coordinates sent by a GPS unit, in decimal degrees.

Comment: For what do you need that for? It is still unclear what you want to achieve. Why not just claculating the delta LatLon or Meters from current to base position?

Comment: There are several different coordinate systems that would use degrees. Moreover, if you need really accurate results on the earth you need to remember it is not exactly spherical. Conversion between distance in meters and  change latitude/longitude is complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You know that releative positions means differences.
So

```
deltaLat = curLat - lastLat;
deltaLon : analog
```

using the absolute lat/lon and all deltas the receiver can recreate the absolute lat/lon position. (There are some pitfalls, make sure to write some unit tests!)

from the current absPosition and the last delta, you easily can calculate the distance in meters.

Addit. info: your deltas should not be in meters, this is very complex. The amount of meters, for two identical deltaLat/Lon pairs varies along the earths globe, so you always need the absolute position (at least the absolute latitude)

Comment: Let me see If I got it right: from the distance of the relative starting position (0,0) and the current relative position (say, (5,3)), we can reverse the Haversine distance formula for two Lat., Long. points, replacing one of the points by the base point. Does this sum it up?

Comment: distances on earth cannot be measured using relative positions, afterwards.  you need absolute one. So think why you need that relative positions. What is your goal? Finally you need two absolute positons to calculate the distance in between. you may reach that by having one absoulte position, and summing up relative delta lat,lon changes. But then finall you get two aboslute positions.

Comment: My goal is, by know the direction of each movement, and the distance of each movement, in meters, to know what is the final destination, knowing I started in point A. I'm afraid there is no way around using relative positions, except maybe measuring distance in a differences of Lat. and Long., which is impossible in my scenario. Is there no way I can convert my X,Y differences in meters to differences in Lat./Long.?

Comment: And why don't you calculate the direction and meters between the last two absolute positions, like everybody does?

Comment: you can convert an x,y differnce to lat/lon, but only if you know the absolute position (at least the absolte latitude). Because the disatnce between two degrees of longitude is only 111.11km at the equator. more north the distaance is 80km, and at the north pole it is near 0.

Comment: I don't compute the distance and direction between the last two directions because I don't have them: I am only able to get the absolute direction in the beginning, and then calculate successive relative positions (see pedestrian dead-reckoning). But you say you can convert (x,y) differences to (Lat., Long.) differences? Using this, I can invert the Haversine formula and find the absolute position. Can you explain a bit further how can I do this or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why doint you have the absolute positions? Where do you get the relative positions from?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I don't have the absolute positions because I don't have a GPS connection: the system I am building gathers GPS positions, and when it loses coverage, it starts computing relative positions via a Pedestrian [Dead-Reckoning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_reckoning) system. Summing it up, I collect one last absolute position before losing satellite coverage, and then start computing displacements from that point onwards.

Comment: ok, search for aviation formulas, there is one for calculating coordinte by given start coord and distance and bearing.